# SSH tunnel to a postgres database

Tags: ssh, postgresql, ssh-tunnel, psql

Currently I develop on a remote dev server. I SSH into the dev server (using SSH keys) as

```
ssh -p 22222 user@devbox.com
```

Then from the dev server, I connect to the database over the local network

```
psql -U postgres -h psqldb -d my_database
```

where `psqldb` points to `10.0.0.202` on the dev server's `/etc/hosts` file.

I want to start developing locally on my own computer. How do I connect to the `psqldb` Postgres server from my local machine by using the remote dev server as an SSH tunnel (or is there a better way to do it)?

**EDIT**

I failed to mention that I already have Postgres installed on my local server and listening on the default port 5432.

Comment: `psql` is a client program. It doesn't listen, it connects...

Answer (score 9):

```
ssh -L localhost:5432:psqldb:5432 -p 22222 user@devbox.com
```

And on another terminal:

```
psql -h localhost -d my_database -U postgres
```

Simple, safe and encrypted. I don't know a better way.

Comment: Actually I already use port 5432 for my local Postgres database on my local machine. If I change the first line to `ssh -L localhost:5433:psqldb:5432 -p 22222 user@devbox.com`, then doing `psql -h localhost -d my_database -U postgres` would just try to connect to my local database.

Comment: The psql command accepts -p to change the port. psql -p 5433 -h ....

Comment: I'm getting an error on the first terminal: `channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`.